# Sleep hygiene in a single-room living space

Tags: sleep, sleep-deprivation, insomnia, environmental-psychology

The principles of sleep hygiene in treating insomnia [(one example)](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2018/sep/14/finally-a-cure-for-insomnia) include addressing the cognitive links between the bedroom and wakefulness - advising that one leave the bed/bedroom if one can't sleep, use the bed/bedroom for sleeping/sex only, and some even recommend changing clothes in other rooms.

But many people live in studios or bedsits - accommodations where there aren't other rooms, and in some extreme cases even where the end of the bed doubles as a chair to work at a desk, and they often don't have a "bed area" distinct from any "working area".

Sleep hygiene recommendations generally seem to presume access to a range of available and distinct spaces/rooms in ones' accommodation, which is often not the case.

How can the links between bed/bedroom and wakefulness be addressed, and what can a chronic insomniac do, in such accommodation?

*(A related problem can be when a bedroom is shared - the advice to get out of bed and leave if unable to sleep, and try again a while later, can be impractical due to the impact on a partners' sleep, unless a second bed/bedroom is available.)*

Comment: This is a pretty good question so I edited it to be clearer.  I am not sure there is going to be an evidence-based answer other than "skip it and do the other sleep hygiene items" but worth a try.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4720388/